# SVN equivalent of git log --name-status

Tags: svn

Want to get all files that were added to my local filesystem when I cloned SVN. git log --name-status does this for git, yet I cannot find an equivalent in SVN.

Ive tried svn status, svn log, svn list yet nothing seems to print out all the files ive added (and in a nice format like git log)

Comment: Doesn't svn print that when you run `svn checkout` or `svn update`?

Comment: I need to be able to capture it whenever i need it (not necessarily right on checkout).. i guess i could just write it to a file  from the checkout, but would rather do it with a command for whenever i need it.

Comment: `svn log --verbose` doesn't work for you? What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn log --verbose` seems equivalent to `git log --name-status`, including list of files added, deleted or modified.

The `--verbose` description from the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.verbose):

> Requests that the client print out as much information as it can while running any subcommand. This may result in Subversion printing out additional fields, detailed information about every file, or additional information regarding its actions.